# Why the same GPIO pin is not working anymore?

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, led

I was working with a very simple code:

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(24,GPIO.HIGH)
```

But after running one time when I am running the code next time the Thonny IDE is showing me

```
RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.OUT)
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GPIO is still working, it's the software refusing to continue without a warning unless you correct the condition causing the warning.

Either do what the warning message says or add the following line at the (logical) end of your script.

```py
GPIO.cleanup()
```